# Media Element JS - check if media file exists or not

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

Is there a way for me to know if media element js can load the file or not? I would like to know if the src passed points to a media file that exists or not.

Or do I need to manually check the file in JQuery using Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might be able to use jQuery's [`.error()`](http://api.jquery.com/error/) function to accomplish your goal?

Comment: I am not sure where to attach that function. Should it be in the audio element?

Comment: well, if you can provide some code, I might be able to help you more specifically